# Why won't my timer function in JS start countdown?

Tags: javascript, function, timer

My countdown timer does not work. I ideally I want it to start when the start buttons is clicked, am I missing something? I've done the event listener on click to the startButton variable, which has a `document.getElementById("start-button")` to the HTML. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```js
let countdownDisplay = document.getElementById("countdown-timer");
let startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
let timer = 60;  //document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
let startGame = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

function countDown () {
    setInterval(function(){
        if (timer <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer = 0)
        }
        countdownDisplay.innerHTML = timer
        timer -= 1
        
    }, 1000)
}
startButton.addEventListener('click', countDown)
```

```html
<div id="start-game">
                 <a class="button" id="start-button" href="quiz.html">Start Game - Kick Off</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When do you run the JS? You also need to prevent the default link handling. What do you think `clearInterval(timer = 0)` will do?

Comment: Note that this can be converted to an executable script here on SO to make things even easier for people.

Answer (score 1):

- Do not use a `<a>` tag with `href` attribute since your page will reload to the new url path. Instead just use a button:
- As **@Scott Marcus** said, do not use `.innerHTML` when the text is not HTML as `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.
- As **@Dave Newton** said, the argument to `clearInterval` should be an interval reference returned by `setInterval`. So relate the interval to a variable.

```js
let countdownDisplay = document.getElementById("countdown-timer");
let startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
let timer = 60;  //document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
let startGame = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

function countDown () {
    let mytimer = setInterval(function(){
        if (timer <= 0) {
            clearInterval(mytimer)
        }
        countdownDisplay.textContent = timer
        timer -= 1
        
    }, 1000)
}
startButton.addEventListener('click', countDown)
```

```html
<div id="start-game">
  <button type="button" class="button" id="start-button">Start Game - Kick Off</button>
  <br>
  <label id="countdown-timer">Start number</label>
</div>
```

Comment: And do not use `.innerHTML` when the text is not HTML as `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: This does not address `clearInterval(timer = 0)`.

Comment: Your timer does not stop.

Comment: @DaveNewton In the snippet it seems to stop ok

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios That is a coincidence--the argument to `clearInterval` should be an interval reference returned by `setInterval`. If you put a `console.log` in the timer function you'll see it's still running. `timer = 0` sets it to `0` if it's `<= 0` so it *looks* like it has stopped.

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios 

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `href` attribute from the anchor - it's causing you to leave/reload the page.

```js
let countdownDisplay = document.getElementById("countdown-timer");
let startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
let timer = 60;
let startGame = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

let t;

function countDown() {

  t = setInterval(function() {
    if (timer <= 0) {
      clearInterval(t)
    }
    countdownDisplay.innerHTML = timer
    timer -= 1

  }, 1000)
}
startButton.addEventListener('click', countDown)
```

```html
<div id="start-game">
  <a class="button" id="start-button">Start Game - Kick Off</a>
</div>
```

Comment: original code does not say it should stop.

Comment: @Jnui  I suggest you read OP's code more carefully. Specifically, "`clearInterval(timer = 0)`"

Answer (score -2):

seems to be ok to me. I adjusted the html to remove link, add element to display countdown and added log.
I removed link because if you click on link you are navigating away from page.

also you should learn how the snippets work on stack overflow, you will get more answers.

```js
let countdownDisplay = document.getElementById("countdown-timer");
let startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
let timer = 60; //document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
let startGame = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

function countDown() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (timer <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer = 0);
    }
    //countdownDisplay.innerHTML = timer;
    timer -= 1;
    countdownDisplay.innerHTML = timer;
    console.log(timer);
  }, 1000)
}
startButton.addEventListener('click', countDown)
```

```html
<div id="start-game">
  <a class="button" id="start-button">Start Game - Kick Off</a>
</div>
<div id="countdown-timer" />
```

Comment: Your timer does not stop.

Comment: *seems to be ok to me. I adjusted the html to remove link,* If it seems ok to you, why remove the link? Maybe because it's not ok to have it?

Comment: Scott Marcus - I should have been more succinct , the essence of the OPs javascript code is fine. My assumption was that the OP thought his javascript code was the cause, it was not. The javascript code did not have any logic bugs, the only issue is the html link.

Comment: Dave Newton - is it supposed to stop? I do not see anything in the OP that says it must stop.